# Current in AC circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-engineering

[image]

The problem is to find the current on the capacitor. $I''$ should be correct, but I don't know how to construct the formula for $I'$.
I managed to get the value for $I_c$ using Thevenin and Norton equivalents, and they're the same, so that should be correct.

Comment: What is the thingy with just a horizontal line in the top schematic?  You really need to properly label things.  If it's meant to be a voltage source, then you can ignore R and L since they have no bearing on the voltage accross the voltage source and therefore the voltage accross the capacitor.

Comment: Would http://electronics.stackexchange.com be a better home for this question?

Comment: That means an open circuit with which you replace i(t).

Comment: @Qmech: EE.SE would be good, but not without a proper definition of whatever the second thingy from the left is. Without it being fixed, I'd jump on it immediately as not a real question on the grounds *it is difficult to tell what is being asked here*, and I think it wouldn't take long for 4 others to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Studying the problem some, I *think* what your showing is superposition of a voltage source and a current source.  In the first circuit, you've zeroed the current source (making it an open circuit), and in the second circuit, you've zeroed the voltage source (making it a short circuit).

In both cases, you appear to be trying to solve for the current through the capacitor and then summing the two results to find the total.

*IF* the sources are sinusoidal with angular frequency $\omega$, then this is a very easy problem to solve.

For the first circuit, the capacitor and resistor are in parallel.  Find the source current and then use current division to find the capacitor current:

$I'_c = \dfrac{U_s}{(R||-jX_C) + jX_L} \dfrac{R}{R -jX_C}$

For the second circuit, you've used current division correctly.

However, it's not clear that AC analysis is appropriate since *the sources are shown as functions of time*.  Since AC analysis is done in the phasor domain, the sources are not shown as time dependent but, rather, as a complex *constant*.

Comment: I admit, the picture was wrong, I used the original circuit picture everywhere, even when using constants. I fixed those too. Your solution is somewhat correct, I don't really get why did you use negative signs here and there, but I got the correct value for I' with this: http://i.imgur.com/8DJaxJY.jpg

Comment: @Garfailed, the negative signs come from this:  $\frac{1}{j} = -j$.  Also, $X_C = \frac{1}{\omega C}$.  Thus:  $\frac{1}{j \omega C} = -jX_C$.

Comment: Oh, I see. It makes sense now.